# how to render same activity if user makes any mistake?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

i am working on a project which has multiple activities. In that one activity called FindActivity.There i have used two edit text and a button. If user enter both the edit text on clicking button it will farword both data to next activity.if user din't enter any values into it,on clicking button it has to give a toast or alert and **have to show the same FindActivity**.except going to my next activity.

now i am doing this with intent(). is there any other way to do this.?

```
shwBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                AutoCompleteTextView city1 = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoCity);
                EditText area1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edArea);

                String aCity = city1.getText().toString();
                String aArea = area1.getText().toString();

                if ((aCity.matches("")) && (aArea.matches(""))) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                            "Please Enter both city and area", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                    Intent myInt = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            SearchActivity.class);
                    startActivity(myInt);
                } else {
                    Intent myInt = new Intent(getBaseContext(),
                            Map1Activity.class);

                    String city = city1.getText().toString();
                    String area = area1.getText().toString();
                    myInt.putExtra("city", city);
                    myInt.putExtra("area", area);
                    startActivity(myInt);

                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Share your code or be clear about your Question.

Comment: you are going from `FindActivity` to other using `Button`? If so, `onClickListener` get the text from the `EditText` and see if its empty or not; If empty show a `Toast` else open the other `Activity`

Comment: Ask your question clearly. When button click you need to validate edittext (Is it have the value or not) ? am I correct ?

Comment: please refer my edited question. And tell me is there any other way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not start any activity in if statement- so it always remain on the same activity.

Try this-

```
if (aCity.length()==0 && length()==0) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                            "Please Enter both city and area", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                   //dont start any activity from here.
                } else {
                    Intent myInt = new Intent(getBaseContext(),
                            Map1Activity.class);

                    String city = city1.getText().toString();
                    String area = area1.getText().toString();
                    myInt.putExtra("city", city);
                    myInt.putExtra("area", area);
                    startActivity(myInt);

                }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ((aCity.matches("")) && (aArea.matches(""))) {
              ......
          .....     
                }
```

instead of your above condition use the below code

```
if(aCity.length()!=0 && aArea.length()!=0){
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter data to proceed ... !",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: thank you karthick. I know this method. I want how to render same activity.? using intent is good or is there any other way..?

Comment: why you need to render same activity again.Is there any necessity to render same activity again ? If there is no user input show toast message or Alert .

Comment: @rubin I had edited my answer too. Please check it

Comment: if i din't render my same activity it will take null data to my next activity

Comment: Which object is null on next activity ? you are passing city and area data to next activity, am I correct?